# Java: force JSlider to be detached/released from mouse when dragged

Tags: java, swing, mouse, drag, jslider

I am using a `JSlider` to seek through an audio file in a custom Java music player application. When the slider is released, the player jumps to the corresponding media time. What I want to achieve is the following: when **`ESCAPE`** is pressed while the slider is being dragged, I want it to be released/detached from the mouse cursor and jump back to its initial position. In other words: I want to interrupt/stop the user's dragging manually.

I have tried the following to achieve this:

1. calling `slider.setValue(initialValue)`
2. firing a custom `mouseReleased()` event (even if the mouse was still being pressed)
3. firing a custom `windowDeactivated()` event on
   the main frame to withdraw the slider its focus

Nothing worked. The slider's knob keeps sticking to the mouse until I physically release it. Is there any other way I can achieve this?

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.border.BevelBorder;
import javax.swing.border.CompoundBorder;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class DetachSlider {

    // true when slider is being dragged
    private boolean dragged;
    
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        new DetachSlider().initFrame();
    }
    
    public void initFrame() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Detach Slider Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                
        JSlider slider = new JSlider();
        slider.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,50));
        slider.addMouseListener(new MouseHandler());
        slider.addKeyListener(new KeyHandler());
        
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBorder(new CompoundBorder(new EmptyBorder(5,5,5,5), new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED)));
        panel.add(slider);

        frame.setContentPane(panel);
        frame.setLocation(500,400);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    // MouseListener for Slider
    private class MouseHandler extends MouseAdapter {
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
            dragged = true;
        }
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) {
            dragged = false;
        }
    }
    
    // KeyListener for Slider
    private class KeyHandler extends KeyAdapter {
        public void keyPressed (KeyEvent ke) {
            if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE) {
                JSlider slider = (JSlider)ke.getSource();
                if (dragged) {
                    System.out.println("ESCAPE pressed when slider is dragged");
                    slider.setValue(0);
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("ESCAPE pressed when slider is idle");
                    slider.setValue(0);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I suggest you to unplug the mouse at that moment and plug it back in - Or grab this guy by the arm. Or better yet remove the Mouse Listener and put Back on!!

Comment: I have given that one a try. I have iterated over the slider's MouseListeners, there were 2: javax.swing.ToolTipManager and javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicSliderUI$TrackListener. I removed them, but the slider kept sticking to the mouse. Furthermore, I was wondering that even after I removed all the MouseListeners, I was still able to drag the slider with the mouse...

Comment: if you could make a simplified version we could try - if you have a big software and you are relying on automated solutions then ok - othrwise take a look at your program and see where the mouse listeners are added - it could be a matter of synchronism etc I'm not too much on the intricasies but if you put up a model we could try

Comment: It seems the event queue holds the mouse event while pressing and anything happening will be executed afterwards- it may get a bit more complicated but you could read on the EventQueue - I dont know if it can be nullified somehow so that events are released - read On!!!

Comment: The mentioned MouseListeners are OOTB listeners, nothing custom. My software is huge and complex, but I have added a simple code snipplet that shows the issue. If ESCAPE is pressed when the slider is dragged, nothing happens. If you don't drag it, its value is set to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I think we have a solution. It is to send the mouseRelease event to all the mouseListeners attached to the slider. As follows:

```
MouseListener[] cs=slider.getMouseListeners();
MouseEvent me = new MouseEvent((JSlider)ke.getSource(), MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED, 0, 0, 100, 100, 1, false);
for(MouseListener m:cs) m.mouseReleased(me);
```

This happens inside the keyPressed method.

Comment: You nailed it! This does the trick. In fact I was really close in one of my initial approaches. So the key is to send the MOUSE_RELEASE event to all attached MouseListeners, not only to the custom one. Thank you very much for your assistance and merry X-mas!